# Show either a node or a blocks page at frontpage

Tags: 8, panels

At the path "/" - the frontpage of my site, I want to show either

- For anonymous users, the content of a particular node, which is normally available at "/somepath".
- For authenticated users, a series of blocks.

How do I do this?

I think the most elegant answer involves using page manager to take control of the "/" route. With this it is easy to show a series of blocks as one variant, but I don't see how to show a particular node.

I have tried setting the "Default front page" at admin/config/system/site-information to "/somepath". But when I do this my panel page defined in page manager does not show up, either when it targets "/" or "/somepath".

As a fallback, I can probably achieve the same result without page manager at all, by choosing to hide the "content" block on the home page and show only the blocks I want. But I worry this gets messy fast, even using the block visibility groups module to avoid repeating the conditions.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. At the moment, for simple things, you can use block visibility to display one block for anonymous and another for authenticated. Dynamic page cache and Block cache should handle things in a scalable way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the block layout gets quite messy when you try to do this. Another option would be a separate twig template for the front page.

Create two new regions `frontpage_auth` and `frontpage_anon` and fill them with the blocks you want to show. Don't configure the visibility here. Just place the blocks.

Modify `page.html.twig`, so that `{{ page.content }}` is enclosed in a twig block `maincontent`:

```
{% block maincontent %}
  {{ page.content }}
{% endblock %}
```

Then create a new twig file for the front page

**page--front.html.twig**

```
{% extends "page.html.twig" %}

{% block maincontent %}

  {% if logged_in %}
    {{ page.frontpage_auth }}
  {% else %}
    {{ page.frontpage_anon }}
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

where you display one of the two regions dependent on the variable `logged_in`.

For the node you can use the *Main page content* block or you can put the node in a view and use this view as a block.